# Play Youtube Url In Webview without userControl in iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, ios7

I want to play youtube url in **UIWebview** or **MPMoviewviewcontroller**.but the restriction is user should not control the playing video.could any one help ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want finer control over youtube videos, theres a library (not written by me) called XCDYoutubeKit.  Search for that and look at incorporating it into your app - theres a class in there that is based on MPMoviePlayerController, that allows the playing of youtube videos from their youtube id (I use it, its good). This also means you get a normal player, so you can pause, scrub through, etc.

Comment: i want to autoplay with perfect constraint